# Transformations on a dataframe after reshaping

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, multi-index

I've read an excel into a dataframe with the following structure

```
df = pd.read_excel(exp_path, skiprows = 20, header = [0,1], index_col=0)
print(df)

                      Unnamed: 1_level_0               average              \
                      Unnamed: 1_level_1 Incidence percentage% Sample size   
NaN                        Gender - Male                  70.0     19119.0   
NaN                      Gender - Female                  30.0     19119.0   
NaN  Gender - I don't identify as either                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                                  NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                                  NaN                   NaN         NaN   
..                                   ...                   ...         ...   
NaN                                  NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                                  NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                                  NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                                  NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                                  NaN                   NaN         NaN   

           Carefree youth                      Urban fellow              \
    Incidence percentage% Sample size Incidence percentage% Sample size   
NaN                  56.0      3033.0                 100.0      1095.0   
NaN                  44.0      3033.0                   0.0      1095.0   
NaN                   0.0      3033.0                   0.0      1095.0   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   
..                    ...         ...                   ...         ...   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   

           Wholesome lady             Progressive professional              \
    Incidence percentage% Sample size    Incidence percentage% Sample size   
NaN                   0.0       999.0                     77.0      1837.0   
NaN                 100.0       999.0                     23.0      1837.0   
NaN                   0.0       999.0                      0.0      1837.0   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                      NaN         NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                      NaN         NaN   
..                    ...         ...                      ...         ...   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                      NaN         NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                      NaN         NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                      NaN         NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                      NaN         NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                      NaN         NaN   

    Unconvetional adventurer                 Pragmetic striver              \
       Incidence percentage% Sample size Incidence percentage% Sample size   
NaN                     75.0       880.0                  81.0      2566.0   
NaN                     25.0       880.0                  19.0      2566.0   
NaN                      0.0       880.0                   0.0      2566.0   
NaN                      NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                      NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   
..                       ...         ...                   ...         ...   
NaN                      NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                      NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                      NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                      NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                      NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   

           Success seeker                   Mature achiever              \
    Incidence percentage% Sample size Incidence percentage% Sample size   
NaN                  84.0      1673.0                  74.0      1146.0   
NaN                  16.0      1673.0                  26.0      1146.0   
NaN                   0.0      1673.0                   0.0      1146.0   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   
..                    ...         ...                   ...         ...   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                   NaN         NaN   

          Joyful indulger             Easy-going trandionalist  \
    Incidence percentage% Sample size    Incidence percentage%   
NaN                  70.0      2311.0                     69.0   
NaN                  30.0      2311.0                     31.0   
NaN                   0.0      2311.0                      0.0   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                      NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                      NaN   
..                    ...         ...                      ...   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                      NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                      NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                      NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                      NaN   
NaN                   NaN         NaN                      NaN   

                     Sophisticated senior                               
        Sample size Incidence percentage%    Sample size Sample size.1  
NaN            2572                    62            974           NaN  
NaN            2572                    38            974           NaN  
NaN            2572                     0            974           NaN  
NaN             NaN                   NaN            NaN           NaN  
NaN             NaN                   NaN            NaN           NaN  
..              ...                   ...            ...           ...  
NaN             NaN                   NaN            NaN           NaN  
NaN             NaN                   NaN            NaN           NaN  
NaN             NaN                   NaN            NaN           NaN  
NaN             NaN                   NaN            NaN           NaN  
NaN  Index  Legend:           Index > 120  Index  80-120    Index <80
```

Utilizing the .stack() method, I was able to transform the dataframe to this:

```
df3 = df.stack(0).reset_index()
    level_0                   level_1 Incidence percentage%     Sample size  \
0       NaN            Carefree youth                  56.0          3033.0   
1       NaN  Easy-going trandionalist                  69.0            2572   
2       NaN           Joyful indulger                  70.0          2311.0   
3       NaN           Mature achiever                  74.0          1146.0   
4       NaN         Pragmetic striver                  81.0          2566.0   
..      ...                       ...                   ...             ...   
35      NaN        Unnamed: 1_level_0                   NaN             NaN   
36      NaN              Urban fellow                   0.0          1095.0   
37      NaN            Wholesome lady                   0.0           999.0   
38      NaN  Easy-going trandionalist                   NaN  Index  Legend:   
39      NaN      Sophisticated senior           Index > 120   Index  80-120   

   Sample size.1                   Unnamed: 1_level_1  
0            NaN                                  NaN  
1            NaN                                  NaN  
2            NaN                                  NaN  
3            NaN                                  NaN  
4            NaN                                  NaN  
..           ...                                  ...  
35           NaN  Gender - I don't identify as either  
36           NaN                                  NaN  
37           NaN                                  NaN  
38           NaN                                  NaN
```

I want to fill the Unnamed: 1_level_1 column similar to the df table. So it should be something like this :

```
               Column  ...                                  Row
0             Carefree youth  ...                        Gender - Male
1   Easy-going trandionalist  ...                        Gender - Male
2            Joyful indulger  ...                        Gender - Male
3            Mature achiever  ...                        Gender - Male
4          Pragmetic striver  ...                        Gender - Male
5   Progressive professional  ...                        Gender - Male
6       Sophisticated senior  ...                        Gender - Male
7             Success seeker  ...                        Gender - Male
8   Unconvetional adventurer  ...                        Gender - Male
9         Unnamed: 1_level_0  ...                        Gender - Male
10              Urban fellow  ...                      Gender - Female
11            Wholesome lady  ...                      Gender - Female
12                   average  ...                      Gender - Female
13            Carefree youth  ...                      Gender - Female
14  Easy-going trandionalist  ...                      Gender - Female
```

I tried with .fillna(), but since the order is different, It is getting filled incorrectly. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You could create a dictionary or a series with the index and the values you assign to each and then `.map`.

Comment: @Rawson, can you elaborate if possible.

Comment: Your dataframes, with so many NaN rows is a bit hard to read and I think using `.map` as I suggested above perhaps won't work.  I think you should set the index as the first column, then stack, then drop the level from the index back to the column, e.g. 

`df.set_index("col_with_gender").stack(0).reset_index(level=0, drop=False)`

where "col_with_gender" is the column name of the column with the "Gender - Male" etc. values.